# Display custom checkout field value in Woocommerce Bookings metadata

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields, woocommerce-bookings

Based on [this description](https://www.wpstud.io/add-custom-select-field-woocommerce-checkout-page/), I made a custom dropdown field to the WooCommerce Checkout Page.

I would like to see this value among the metadata in Woocommerce Bookings plugin.
[Bookings: Action and Filter reference](https://woocommerce.com/document/bookings-action-and-filter-reference/)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_booking_data_after_booking_details', 'wps_select_checkout_field_display_booking_order_meta');
function wps_select_checkout_field_display_booking_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Communication').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'comm_plat', true ) . '</p>';

}
```

But I only see the 'Communication:' text, without the value.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at your `echo` statement the following are possible reasons you are not seeing the value:

1:  `'comm_plat'` is not save to `post_meta` as such it is returning empty string

2: `'comm_plat'` might be wrongly spelled when saving the value which means you are querying with a wrong name

3: On the link you provided there is no hook with the name `woocommerce_admin_booking_data_after_booking_details` the closest to that was `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address`

4: Is the `$order` parameter passed to the hooked (you can know this by printing out the `$order` variable like so:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_booking_data_after_booking_details', 'wps_select_checkout_field_display_booking_order_meta');
function wps_select_checkout_field_display_booking_order_meta($order){
  print_r($order)
}
```

Comment: 1. and 2. 
Here you can see the code of the custom field.  https://onlinephp.io/c/c13cb
3. woocommerce_admin_booking_data_after_booking_details is the second action on the list

By the way, after modifying the relevant file of the woocommerce bookings plugin, the value appears, but I would like to solve it with a hook.

Comment: You can as well use `do_action` to  create custom hook on file you edited if the will be okay

Comment: Another thing is to check carefully what you edited to make it work and see if that is passed to the hooked. EG if the `$order` parameter is passed. You can know this by printing out the `$order` variable itself.

Comment: I get back the order ID if I use `print_r($order)`, so it passed to the hook. The aim is to not change the plugins' file, so I don't want to add an extra hook.